# web browser in C# without using my own web browser class

Tags: c#, web-applications, bitmap, browser, xelement

i have no idea about what im doing the problem is that i got the assignment without any further explanation all what i have to do is make a program with main form that will load an html file into it but without using web browser class and the Html will contain a text and images and the only hint i got is i'll be using "Xelement to read the file from a Dom tree and render it into a bitmap file that will be displayed into the form"

Comment: Please review this post about homework questions.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused by your question. Are you looking for this?

[Internet Explorer Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It is a browser you can manipulate in your code.

Addendum:

Or perhaps is it this you need?

1. Create HttpWebRequest Object
2. Create HttpWebResponse Object
3. Get Html Source

[Here is a guide.](http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/994.html)

The Html Source will have the DOM Object:

1. Navigate with Xelement
2. Print elements as you discover them in the DOM.

Comment: i couldn't do any thing because as i said i have no idea about what im doing the problem is that i got the assignment without any further explanation all what i have to do is making a program with main form that will load an html file into it but without using web browser class and the Html will contain a text and images and the only hint i got is i'll be using "Xelement to read the file from a Dom tree and render it into a bitmap file that will be displayed into the form" and sorry for confusing you but i'm confused also